# Exporting data to another workbook using msgbox with BeforeClose

Tags: excel, vba

At the end of using a spreadsheet when the user wishes to leave the file I wish to add a message box asking whether the individual wishes to export the data. I have added the message box fine under the BeforeClose section, however the data will not export when Yes is selected. When yes is selected I receive a notification stating "Subscript out of range". I would like to know why this is.

Excel VBA, thisWorkbook

```
Private Sub Workbook_BeforeClose(Cancel As Boolean)

Dim Output As String

Output = MsgBox("Are you ready to export the data?", vbYesNo, "Data Export")

If Output = vbYes Then

Range("AJ" & Cells.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Copy

Workbooks.Open Filename:="S:\US Div\Accounts\filename.xlsx"

Worksheets("Input P").Range("C7").Paste

End If

End Sub
```

Comment: Do you have a `worksheet` called `Input P` in the target workbook?

Comment: Try this: Sheets("Input P").Range("C7").PasteSpecial

Comment: Workbooks.Open returns a workbook object. You should write: `Set wb=Workbook.Open …` and `Dim wb as Workbook …`, and `wb.Worksheets("Input P").Range("C7").Paste`